# build.template not found when creating an android project in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, mobile

I've been having issues with Cordova. I can add the android platform but when I try to build an error appears saying that build.template is not in C:users\scott\devolopment\adt-bundle\tools\lib\build.template as seen in the image below

[image]

However I do have build.template in that location as seen below

[image]

So I'm confused as to why it cant find it. I have appended the tools and the platform tools to my path. I've tried closing the command prompt and reopening it as well as restarting the computer. However I still get the same error every time. Anyone have any ideas